# lightbox scrolling past page bottom

Tags: jquery, html, css, lightbox

Ok, so I'm by no means an expert in css, jquery, or any of these new fangled html 5 element.

I'm trying to use the lightwindow lightbox script to make a simple gallery, but I'm having this weird problem in firefox (not in ie 8, though).

When the lightbox is open, it creates a scroll bar next to the page's scroll bar, and it allows the page to scroll well below the content into this uncharted grey territory.

the page is here
:http://highburypools.com/newsite/liners.php

I've googled this to death, and though I've found what people claim to be solutions, it's all fragmented gibberish to me and I have no idea how to implement these solutions.

Thanks!

Comment: The plugin you are using is setting the css inline height of the `#lightwindow_overlay` element to `1938px`. That would be causing the long scrolling. You will want to look at how the plugin is calculating the height.

Comment: ok, got it.  the lightbox.js file has this if block: if(Prototype.Browser.Gecko) {
      overlay.setStyle({
          backgroundImage: 'url('+this.options.overlay.presetImage+')',
          backgroundRepeat: 'repeat',
          height: this.pageDimensions.height + 'px' 
          height: 700 + 'px'
      });                                                                  so basically, i just replaced the line where it sets height to height: 700 + 'px',    it's weird that FF thinks the pages has over 1900px of height, because the page properties says it has only 1200.  A firefox bug maybe?

Comment: Perfect! You can put your solution as an answer then mark the question as answered.

Comment: I'm new here.  I can for the life of me figure out how to do that.  There's got to be some button somewhere....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, got it. The `lightbox.js` file has this if block:

```
if(Prototype.Browser.Gecko) { overlay.setStyle({ backgroundImage: 'url('+this.options.overlay.presetImage+')', backgroundRepeat: 'repeat', height: this.pageDimensions.height + 'px' height: 700 + 'px' });
```

So basically, I just replaced the line where it sets height to height: 700 + 'px', it's weird that FF thinks the pages has over 1900px of height, because the page properties says it has only 1200. A firefox bug maybe?